# Extend Datatables "fnInitComplete"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I understand you can set defaults for all Datatables as so:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "num-html-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

but I'd like to set a default function for fnInitComplete that will work along with/not override this function elsewhere - so a default. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `fnInitComplete` default:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) { doSomething(); }
});
```

In order to prevent it from being overridden when setting up your data table, you can do like this:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    //lots of other properties here
    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
       $.fn.dataTable.defaults.fnInitComplete(oSettings, json);
       doSomethingElse();
    }
});
```